# Trouble understanding where a variable is defined

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Alright, I'm following this codecademy python course, and my code is correct, but I don't fully understand it. I had to go on the forums to find the correct answer.  Here's the code:

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
     "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
     "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
     "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
     "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score(word):
    total = 0
    #Make my word lowercase even when i type in caps
    t = word.lower()

    for key in t:
        total += score[key]
    return total
print scrabble_score(raw_input("Your word: "))
```

I get everything except this:

```
total += score[key]
```

How does the script know what the "score" variable is? I haven't defined it anywhere. Is this a global variable?
EDIT: I was kind of tired when asking this question(Had been awake 23-25 hours to be exact). I Now see that i actually defined the variable.

Comment: It looks like `score` is a global dictionary.  You usually want to avoid globals in Python unless they are constants such as `PI = 3.141592`.

Comment: `score` is probably defined in the global scope

Comment: Globals are nearly always a bad idea. Avoid them if you can.

Comment: "Global" is your answer - score has a "Global" scope.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Anyone knows how I could do this without the score? Or rather without using a global?

Comment: @ZanderMøysal       You could simply use score as an argument in your `scrabble_score(word, score)` function.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code, a good option would be to put it in a class.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to put in the dictionary i used. Editing the main post now. Haven't learned about classes yet though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to change your solution to this if required:

```
def scrabble_score(word,score): # score doesn't need to be global
    total = 0
    t = word.lower()
    for key in t:
        total += score[key]
    return total

x = raw_input("Enter word: ")
# declare what score is here
print(srabble_score(x,score))
```

Comment: Does that mean i can replace 'score' with whatever variable i want?

Comment: @ZanderMoysal      yes. But at the same time,the score has to be meaningful too. You are using score[key] that suggests score is a string/list/tuple/dictionary.

Comment: For testing purposes I replaced the 'score' var's with 'eggs'. And It threw me an error saying that 'eggs' was not defined. But anyways, thanks. @hagubear

Comment: @ZanderMøysal     Yes, but your score is supposed to be dictionary isn't it? Like the one you posted in the question?

Comment: Probably more misleading here was the choice of variable name "key", probably because it is used as the key into the `score` lookup table. If it were called "letter", then things might have been clearer. In fact, I think this one-line implementation of `scrabble_score` is quite readable: `return sum(score[letter] for letter in word.lower())`. And all this admonishment against globals is only relevant once your program grows beyond multiple source files - in a short assignment like this, I think a global `score` table is perfectly fine.